# What should be the after shocks off a super solider murdering a dozen protestors in broad daylight and then burning down a building they retreated to?

Tags: super-powers

I guess I'm saying this because in my current story chapter, that I just wrote today, I had my main character gun down a dozen union protestors and then burn down a building the survivors were hiding in after they retreated after the obvious chaos and violence.

Altogether the five super soldiers (who are our nominal protagonists) killed approximately 120 - 190 people at this protest similar to the [Banana Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Massacre). However this was done in Modern day Australia which is still a Developed Nation. Furthermore the soldiers didn't do this on orders. They just got angry at the racial slurs hurled at them by the protestors and responded violently.

Although the Super Soliders are only beholden to an Cybernetic AI that watches things from afar they're mostly a beneficial force since they fight certain Demonic forces (Story is complicated) and Aliens.

Still for this massacre what should be the general reactions world wide?

Comment: Seems to be a plot point rather than building a world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Long term storage.**

[image: sierra army depot]
[source](https://www.defensemedianetwork.com/stories/the-home-base-providing-a-second-life-for-army-equipment/)

These supersoldiers have (amply) proven themselves too dangerous for civilian duties.  But they are expensive weapons and may have uses for future military engagements (demon fighting etc).

They will be removed from the civilian sphere in the same manner as war weapons not currently needed for war.  In the civilian press it will be stated that these supersoldiers will be prosecuted for their crimes.  The trial will happen, sentences set and so on but the very dangerous individuals involved will not partipate in person in these trials because they are too dangerous.  Actors may participate.  Justice will be said to be done.

The supersoldiers will actually be moved to a secure facility.  It is a cross between a prison and an armory.  They will train and be entertained and supported.  They will not have an opportunity to hurt civilians but they will be available and ready for military endeavors.

This facility already existed.  There were groups who felt the supersoldiers should have been stored there in the first place but they were overruled by other factions who thought this newest generation supersoldier was better than similar previous entities and could be trusted for civilian use.  On arriving at the facility, the supersoldiers will encounter the entities who live there now, and for whom this facility was built.  They will also encounter occult and alien weaponry which is researched at the facility.  Their tour guide can be a defector Alien.